Preserve variable from toMail() when code fails
I want to log events when sending of email fails, but have a problem where the variable of the created email log entry ID is not preserved and forwarded with the code.
This is my Notification class:
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Routering\User\Notifications;

use App\Models\MailTemplate;
use App\Modules\Email\Entity\MailTag;
use App\Modules\Reports\SentEmail\Entity\SentEmail;
use App\Modules\Routering\Organisation\Entity\Organisation;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Markdown;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Events\NotificationFailed;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Throwable;

class ResetPassword extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * The password reset token.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $token;

    protected mixed $notifiable;
    protected mixed $sentEmailId = null; // <-- this one is important, please follow it in the code

    /**
     * Create a notification instance.
     *
     * @param string $token
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's channels.
     *
     * @param mixed $notifiable
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function via(mixed $notifiable): array
    {
        $this->notifiable = $notifiable;
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param mixed $notifiable
     *
     * @return MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail(mixed $notifiable): MailMessage
    {
        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
        }

        $url = config(
                $notifiable->access_type === 'client-portal'
                    ? 'app.client_portal_url'
                    : 'app.public_url'
            ) . '/auth/reset-password/' . $this->token .
            '?email=' . $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset();

        if (!empty($notifiable->organisation)) {
            $organisation = $notifiable->organisation;
        } else {
            $organisation = Organisation::where('name', '...')->first();
        }

        $variables = [
            ...
        ];

        $mailTemplateId = 2;
        $template = (new MailTemplate())->getContent($mailTemplateId, $variables);

        // here, the email with it's content is stored in the database
        // and an ID is returned. This works well.
        $this->sentEmailId = SentEmail::create([
            'mail_template_id' => $mailTemplateId,
            'mail_tag_id' => MailTag::where('name', 'authentication')->first()->id,
            'content' => (new Markdown(view(), config('mail.markdown')))->render('email::template', [
                    'logo' => $variables['logo'],
                    ...['body' => $template->body],
                    ...$variables]
            ),
            'recipient' => $notifiable->email,
            'subject' => $template->subject,
        ])->id;

        return (new MailMessage())
            ->withSymfonyMessage(function ($message) {
                $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('O:TAG', MailTag::where('name', 'authentication')->first()->name);
            })
            ->subject($template->subject)
            ->markdown('email::template', [
                ...['body' => $template->body],
                ...$variables
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Call the failed method on the notification instance.
     *
     * @param Throwable $e
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function failed(Throwable $e): void
    {
        // when sending of email fails (forced failure for testing),
        // the `sendEmailId` is `null`, despite I set it in previous function.
        dd($this->sentEmailId);
        $notifiable = $this->getNotifiable();
        if ($notifiable) {
            event(new NotificationFailed($notifiable,
                $this,
                $this->via($notifiable)[0],
                'E-mail adres: ' . $notifiable . '<br>Notitie: ' . $e->getMessage()
            ));
        }
    }

    private function getNotifiable(): string|null
    {
        if (!empty($this->notifiable->routes['mail'])) {
            return $this->notifiable->routes['mail'];
        } elseif (!empty($this->notifiable->email)) {
            return $this->notifiable->email;
        } elseif (!empty($this->notifiable)) {
            return $this->notifiable;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

As you can see, in toMail() function I assign sentEmailId with the ID from the database once the record has been created. This works well, since I do see an entry in database and if I dd() here, I also get ID back. The problem is with failed() function because sentEmailId is null and I can't log failed event to the correct email.
How can I preserve the sentEmailId to be used in the rest of the code?

Are you sure an actual id is being returned when SentEmail::create fails?

SentEmail::create is not failing, that would be another issue. id is there, but as said, it's not preserved between toMail and failed. If I print it out in toMail, I do see an id, but if the code fails and failed is being called, the sentEmailId is null. Despite I see entry created in database.

The only way sentEmailId is not being preserved is either A) $this->sentEmailId = ... never get called or B) There is another request before you access failed or C) You are accessing another instance of the class

I didn't dive into laravel's code, but to me it looks like it creates a snapshot of the class before it executes toMail and if it fails, it provides "old" snapshot to the failed method. Because I also assign notifiable in via function and that one is preserved.

Then I'd advise you to add some logging to find out how the code is actually executed
